# find the exact amount which can not pay off a loan (avoid infinite loop)

Tags: c, infinite-loop

Here's my code for a simple C program that will calculate the interest paid on 
a loan. I don't have any question on the codes. But I can not figure out a way to find the exact payment amount which can not pay off the loan(that amount will lead to an infinite loop). I only know that the amount should be somewhere around 41.7. Is there a smart way to do this? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float p;
    float i;
    float temp, ti = 0;
    int a = 1;

    printf("Please enter your monthly payment: ");
    scanf("%f", &p);
    printf("\n");

    float r = 0.25;
    float b = 2000.0;

    printf("r = %.2f\nB = %.1f\nP = %.1f \n\n", r, b, p);

    i = (r/12) * b;
    temp = i;
    printf("%d  %.2f  %.2f\n", a, i, b);
    a ++;

    while(i > 0)
    {
        i = (r/12) * (b - p + temp);
        b = (b - p + temp);
        ti += temp;
        temp = i;
        printf("%d  %.2f  %.2f\n", a, i, b);
        a ++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("total interest paid: %.2f\n", ti);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to manually compound the interest when the monthly payment is constant?  You can't just calculate the amount of interest that will be added, since any payment rate lower than that interest will not pay off the loan?

Comment: What has `41.7` to do with the question?

Comment: Nothing. I just want to know the exact value instead of 41.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program will go into an infinite loop when the monthly payment is less than the monthly interest value.
In the given code,

```
i = (r/12) * (b - p + temp);
```

determines the infinite loop condition.

For the loop to terminate

```
p > temp
p > (r / 12) * b
```

Substituting values give,

```
p > (0.25 / 12) * 2000
p > 41.66
```